App crash only on iOS after successful WebAuthenticator callback via Universal App Link
I'm migrating a .NET MAUI iOS authorization flow from one that handles redirect using the now-deprecated custom URL scheme to one that employs an Universal App Link verified via a apple-app-site-association file hosted on Firebase.
The callback works. The code is received successfully. The issue is that the app crashes upon returning from the WebAuthenticator authorization flow. This is a problem with iOS only, not Android which works perfectly using an Android App Link served by a assetlinks.json file on the same server.
Short question
Have you gotten this to work? In that case skip all the laborious details and walk me through it! Otherwise, here is...

What I've tried

Verify the Universal App Link using the Developer settings on iPhone.




With the app debugger attached, inject the URL in Safari from a special "redirect test" page on our server. Verify that a breakpoint in ContinueUserActivity is hit. Verify that the app does not crash when the Universal App Link is exercised in this manner.



Setting a breakpoint to inspect the returned authorization code. Then returning immediately to avoid any possibility of other exceptions.

buttonLogin.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var clientId = "123456789012-1ok9rauo969og7aljrnri1gesrr7l1b3.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    var redirectUrl = "https://myfirebasedomain.com/auth";
    var scopes = "profile%20openid%20email";
    var authUrl = $"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}&prompt=consent&response_type=code&scope={scopes}&access_type=offline";

    Uri authUri = new Uri(authUrl);
    Uri callbackUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);

    WebAuthenticatorResult result;
    try
    {
        result = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions
        {
            Url = authUri,
            CallbackUrl = callbackUri,
            PrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
        });
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // 'Not' an error. The user simply cancelled this op.
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    // Exchange the authorization code for an access token

    var payload = new
    {
        code = result.Properties["code"],
        redirectUri = redirectUrl,
        clientId = clientId,
        key = "web",
    };
    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage? response = null;
    string? error = null;

    try
    {
        // Exchange token using secret stored on server.

        // We are unable to attempt this. The async post causes this 
        // method to return, and when it does, the app crashes.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        if (response != null)
        {
            error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        Debug.Fail(error ?? "null");
    }
};

Value of jsonPayload indicates success
{
  "code": "4/0AanRRrte8fELNx0CyzgsPzrGCo46TLvkp_JhQaG0ao8DMmVLySwN4_8KIfAXNiouGAqkrQ",
  "redirectUri": "https://myfirebasedomain.com/auth",
  "clientId": "123456789012-1ok9rauo969og7aljrnri1gesrr7l1b3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "key": "web"
}



Going up a level to wrap the ContinueUserActivity for exceptions. I can set a breakpoint on return result. The crash occurs if this method is allowed to run from that point.

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            // Calling the BC is what causes the AuthenticateAsync task to complete.
            result = base.ContinueUserActivity(application, userActivity, completionHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // NO exception being caught here.
        }
        return result;
    }
}


My question:
AFAIK I'm doing everything right, but can anyone spot any reason for the crash? I'm inclined to log it as a bug against WebAuthenticator for iOS, but before I do anything dumb please "check my work!"

Crash Log (iPhone 11 physical device)

Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
INFO:   0x1a3be2db0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a390977c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__

INFO:   0x1a3c6677c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO: 014e7888 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path
    0x101842cdc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1c72e0de8 - /usr/lib/dyld : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x19e5d634c):0x19e5d633c  21 20 37 91 30 06 00 14 00 00 00 ea 6d ff ff 54  ! 7.0.......m..T
0x19e5d634c  10 00 
INFO: 0x19e5d635c  30 04 00 36 11 
INFO:   0x1a3abee00 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3c02410 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3908434 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3886350 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO: Disposing input and output streams...
INFO:   0x1a10d5bbc - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a10d21b0 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a1124274 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific

INFO:   0x1a38863c0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a2c47008 - /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3908434 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3c02410 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3c02790 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3886350 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3909718 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3ac1944 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1c4e37488 - /System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3abee00 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1017efa50 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017d1d0c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x22bba8ca8 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>

INFO: 
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================

INFO: Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

INFO:   0x101804b64 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection

INFO:   0x1a8e0bfa8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a8e1aa34 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a8e1a64c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF

INFO:   0x1014e7888 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : xamarin_get_original_working_directory_path
    0x101842cdc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1c72e0de8 - /usr/lib/dyld : <redacted>

Exiting early due to double fault.

INFO:   0x1a1124274 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x1ee26d4c0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x1a3c6677c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a388ce64 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x1014bc5f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : xamarin_UIApplicationMain
    0x101815404 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101813d04 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101808714 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1018062ac - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncP
INFO:   0x1a2c47008 - /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : <redacted>
    0x1a8e0bfa8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a8e1aa34 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a8e1a64c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
    0x1a10d5bbc - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a10d21b0 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a38863c0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a390977c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__

INFO:   0x1a3909718 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO: roxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017d4e84 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x10177c548 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101782844 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017da4a0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection

INFO:   0x1a3c02790 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3ac1944 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:   0x1a3be2db0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

INFO:     at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00152>
      at GoogleDriveLocalSyncProxy.Maui.TestProject.Program:Main <0x0002c>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x0007e>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

An error has occurred in the native fault reporting. Some diagnostic information will be unavailable.

INFO: 
=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x101804b64 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017efa50 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017d1d0c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection

INFO: ...

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:xamarin_UIApplicationMain <0x000b8>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x0006e>

INFO:   0x22bba8ca8 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1c4e37488 - /System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices : <redacted>

INFO:  `..T. .......
INFO: fe 77 d3 91 fe ff b4 3f 06 00 f1  0..6..w.....?...
INFO:  ..@...}.Q.@.1..6

INFO: 40 f9 02 82 7d 92 51 10 40 f9 31 03 10 36 
INFO:   0x1018062ac - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017d4e84 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x10177c548 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101782844 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1017da4a0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x1
INFO:   0x1a388ce64 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x1014bc5f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : xamarin_UIApplicationMain
    0x101815404 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101813d04 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection
    0x101808714 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D3ED65C-DDCD-40D0-A24A-BE6EDA007591/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy.app/IVSoftware.Maui.EchoesSyncProxy : AppleCryptoNative_X509ImportCollection

INFO:   0x1ee26d4c0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal

INFO: 
0x19e5d636c  60 02 00 54 11 20 e0 d2 11 02 11 cb e1 03 10 aa 
INFO: Closing debug connection from remote debugger (TCP)
INFO: Closing debug connection from device (USB)
The app has been terminated.
INFO: Disposing input and output streams...
INFO: Disposing console and debugger streams...
ERROR: An error occurred while writing to the debug stream. Details: ObjectDisposed_Generic
ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name, UsbStream


I found there is a new issue about this problem here. You can follow it up here.
